# How to fix message sent to deallocated error

Tags: ios, memory-management, nszombies

I am passing two string using delegate to the parent controller while I pop to the parent controller.

```
    if (![clientIdd length] == 0)
    {
        [self.clientIdDelegate passClientId:clientIdd andCouncelorId:councelorId];

        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

I enabled Zombies and am getting an error like this:

`[CFString respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7a77f8e0.`

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you post full crash log?

Comment: I guess clientId is dead

Comment: - -[CFString respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7a77f8e0 - this the log msg

Comment: How do you declare delegate instance? weak or strong?

Comment: Muzahidul i have declared it as strong

Comment: This line `if (![clientIdd length] ==0)` is really getting bugs(and all other insects) out of my head. This check you are making is wrong, and only empty strings pass it. Change it to `if (!([clientIdd length]==0))` or `if ([clientIdd length]!=0)` or `if (clientIdd && [clientIdd length] > 0)`, and try, maybe it will work (last one is better). Also, put check like that for your `councelorId`, it also can be `nil` or empty.

Comment: It seems that you are calling a delegate and then you try to pop the controller from the screen.
Do you have an async request / piece of code in the `[self.clientIdDelegate passClientId:clientIdd andCouncelorId:councelorId];` method or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether clientIdd is NSNull using the following code.

`if(clientIdd == (id)[NSNull null])`

if it is the case then find out the reason for clientIdd becoming null in your code.